# How can i deploy a node app using ffmpeg to heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg

Struggling to go from local development to deploying my web app. using ffmpeg in node to crop things. tried following this guide to deploying ffmpeg, https://github.com/HYPERHYPER/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg, and how the binary needs to be in a buildpack. Achieved this, but it still doesn't work. How do i reference the buildpack?

is is something to do with this line?
     .setFfmpegPath('./ffmpeg')

```
   var fileName = './new_crops/' + videoTitle + '.mp3';
    var process = new ffmpeg({
            source: videoGrab
        })
        .setFfmpegPath('./ffmpeg')
        .audioBitrate(info.formats[0].audioBitrate)
        .withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
        .toFormat('mp3')
        .outputOptions('-id3v2_version', '4')
        .outputOptions('-metadata', 'title=' + title)
        .outputOptions('-metadata', 'artist=' + artist)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `./` from the ffmpeg path. According to the buildpack documentation, the app is installed in the server path, so it's globally available.

The full path where the executable is located is `/app/vendor/ffmpeg/bin`.

Comment: remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack
remote:

Comment: That's an error from heroku (and the buildpack) itself, it's not related to where and how you might run `ffmpeg`.

Comment: PS: According to the documentation, you need [the multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) in order to run the `ffmpeg` buildpack. It doesn't work standalone.